# Running 3 External monitors from a Macbook Pro Retina 13" Mid 2014

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I currently own a Macbook pro (Retina 13",mid 2014)
2.6GHz Intel Core i5
8GB 1600 Mhz DDR3
Intel Iris 1536 mb

3 x 22" Samsung Monitors. 2 of them running through Thunderbolt to DVI-D adapter.

The 3 monitor i have tried using both a DVI-D to HDMI convertor and USB to DVI convertor.

But i just can't get the 3rd monitor to run.  Any thoughts?? Is my specs not enough to run all the monitors?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your computer can only drive up to two external displays (officially, at least). https://support.apple.com/kb/SP703?locale=en_US